# how to select parent id from the child id

Tags: sql-server

I am having a table name `factors`. It contains data like this:

```
id      Name         paretnID
1       abc           0
2       xyz           0
3       abc1          1
4       abc2          1
5       abc3          1
6       qwe           0
7       xyz1          2
8       xyz2          2
```

I have a set of ids like this: `(1,4,7,8)`

I want to show all the parent and child ids.
Like this

```
id      name       parentID
1       abc         0
2       xyz         0
4       abc2        1
7       xyz1        2
8       xyz2        2
```

In my id list `2` is not present but id `2` is the parent of `7` and `8` so it is showing in the result set.

How to write query to show above result?

Comment: Why `3`,`5` and `6` are not in the results?

Comment: @ypercube for my understanding he wants all nodes in (1,4,7,8) and the needed parents

Comment: right @bummi, you are right

Comment: @bummi Right, I hadn't read the ***"I have a set of ids like this(1,4,7,8)"*** line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @a table (id  int ,    Name  Varchar(100) ,      parentID int)
Insert into @a
Select 1,'abc',0
UNION Select 2,'xyz',0
UNION Select 3,'abc1',1
UNION Select 4,'abc2',1
UNION Select 5,'abc3',1
UNION Select 6,'qwe',0
UNION Select 7,'xyz1',2
UNION Select 8,'xyz2',2


;WITH Rollups AS (
    SELECT Id, ParentId,Name
    FROM @a Child WHERE ID in (1,4,7,8)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cl.Id, cl.ParentId, cl.Name
    FROM @a cl 
    INNER JOIN Rollups Children ON Children.ParentID = cl.Id
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Rollups
Order by ID
```

Comment: it is one query staring with `;WITH` and ending with `Order by ID` @a would be your table. Without using CTE you won't get the desired result if your tree has more then two levels.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
SELECT 
  id.name,parentid 
FROM 
  factors 
WHERE 
  id IN (1,4,7,8)

UNION

SELECT 
  p.id.p.name,p.parentid 
FROM factors c 
JOIN factors p
ON c.parentid = p.id
WHERE 
  c.id IN (1,4,7,8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, solved it with something like this...

```
SELECT b.*
FROM factors AS a
JOIN factors AS b
ON a.parentID = b.id
WHERE a.id IN (1,4,7,8)
```